# React datepicker set selected dynamically

Tags: html, reactjs

I use react-datepicker library in my React application. By default selected date is today, once user select a date and submit the form, there is an action that set the selected date back to today

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date())

<DatePicker
    selected={startDate}
    onChange={date => changeDate(date)}
    inline
/>
```

and this is the action I'm talking

```
const saveData = () => {
    // send data to the server
    ...
    // reset startDate to its initial value (today)
    setStartDate(new Date());
}
```

The `saveData` method is indeed highlighting the today date, but also the user selected date is still being highlighted, as shown in the picture.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Sandbox code might be of help: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-dust-yfiw3q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: A working example of your code would be helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `startDate` in `value`

```js
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

const changeDate = date => {
  setStartDate(date);
}

<DatePicker
  value={startDate}   //add this
  onChange={date => changeDate(date)}
  inline
/>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but the issue still persisted when `value` prop is added

Comment: try removing `selected={startDate}`

Comment: nope, doesn't even highlighting today date once the form submitted.

Comment: Could you please show your `changeDate` function

Comment: changeDate body function is just as simple as `setStartDate(date)`, I am just following what the documentation said.

Comment: This code above is working for me in codesandbox

Comment: If it's still not working, please provide a working example of your code.

Comment: please try this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-dust-yfiw3q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It's working fine in codesandbox

Comment: no.. it's not. thanks for your help, but your solution doesn't help.

Comment: In the codesandbox I'm not able to reproduce the thing which you mentioned in the screenshot.